# JS output directly to database?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Sudo-code:

```
function findAllPaths(allStarts){
    function makePath(start){
        var path = [{"1,1" : 1}, {"1,2" : 2}, {"2,2" : 3},{"2,1" : 4}]
        return path;
    }
    var solutions = [];
    for(i=0;i<allStarts.length;i++){
         solutions.push(makePath(allStarts[i]));
    }
    return solutions;
}
console.log(findAllPaths(1,1));

// Every time the code runs, it outputs thousands to millions of paths.
```

Is there a way to run a js script directly in mongo?

My JS file generates a JSON object with results. I tried running the script in node, saving the output to a .txt file. Eventually it terminated with the error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 100501 ms: Scavenge 1413.8 (1457.9) -> 1413.8 (1457.9) MB, 30.1 / 0
>   ms (+ 3.4 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure]
>   [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].   102369 ms: Mark-sweep
>   1413.8 (1457.9) -> 1413.8 (1457.9) MB, 1867.8 / 0 ms (+ 4.1 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.4 ms) [last resort gc].
>   104270 ms: Mark-sweep 1413.8 (1457.9) -> 1413.8 (1457.9) MB, 1901.7 /
>   0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x1b9a709b4629 
>       1: setPrototypeOf [native v8natives.js:~653] [pc=0x196157b79485] (this=0x1b9a70990fa9 ,J=0x1ba6e8004101 ,am=0xb24ead25bf9 )
>       2: log [console.js:~35] [pc=0x196157b784e8] (this=0x38b6577c5a19 )
>       3: arguments adaptor frame: 1...

Instead of using an output file, I would like to save my JSON to mongodb. Is it possible to do this without first running the code in Node?

Comment: Please, be more specific. A little piece of code maybe

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: you can use [Mongo Shell scripts](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) or Node.js scripts.

A Mongo Shell script can be run in Mongo Shell directly or loaded there from a file.

In a Node.js script you can use one of the [MongoDB packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongodb) or an [official driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).